# How I could do this in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have this table in which C = A+B;
 
after this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (A INT, B INT, C INT);
INSERT INTO foo (A,B) values (1,2),(4,5);
SELECT * FROM foo;
```

results this:

```
A | B | C
--+---+----
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 9
```

How to say to MySQL that C always is C = A+B in the create table clause;
Thank you guys; I'm gonna use the this "SELECT A,B,A+B AS C FROM foo;" it seems work as I want.thanks

Comment: set a trigger on the table to update the `c` field anytime something's updated/isnerted into `a` or `b`.

Comment: `mysql> SELECT A, B, (A + B) as C FROM foo;`

Comment: It's better not to do this in database level. If you want to SELECT C, just SELECT (A + B)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a column C in your table, but use a computed column in your SELECT:

```
SELECT
    A,
    B,
    A + B AS C
FROM
    foo
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL lacks the two features you could use:

- Calculated columns (aka virtual columns)
- Check constraints

So you're basically left with:

- Writing triggers to make the calculation on insert and keep it updated on update
- Writing a view

Other than that, calculated columns can also be... well, calculated on select as other answers point out. Storing duplicate information in the database is normally discouraged except for very specific performance tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_data (A INT, B INT, C INT);
CREATE VIEW foo_ext AS SELECT A, B, (A+B) AS C FROM foo_data;
INSERT INTO foo_data (A,B) values (1,2),(4,5);
SELECT * FROM foo_ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if your geting input from user 

$c = $_POST['a'] +$_POST['b'];
<p>
</p>
INSERT INTO foo (C) values ($c);
```

Comment: This does not prevent to modify only A or B which in turn violates the constraint `C = A + B`.

Answer (score 0):

select A,B,A+B as C from C same answer like VMai